# How to transition from old content to new properly

Tags: wordpress

Can you advise on how I go after redesigning pages to transition?

1. We have upgraded our contents from our current website.
2. The new pages have the same name, only this time, for site health and page ranking the navigation/menu is different, this means some old pages will be gone:

Pages current(and how they are on menu):

1. home (page)
2. feed me mother > menu, aperitivo alla milanese, how we do it
3. Swinging brunch
4. drinks > menu, how we do it
5. come to mother

Pages Future:

1. home page
2. menu
3. how we do it
4. come to mother

Could I just use the same old pages? and paste my new content there, and redirect to desired pages, for the old pages that we will not be using anymore?

I hope you can help me! A bit confusing, I'm still new to the whole process, and is a concern that we will lose the traffic if I do it wrong.

Looking forward to hearing from you.
Thanks

Right now all test mockup pages for the new design are in private.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed keep the old pages, keep their slug and just add new content.
Otherwise if you wish to have a new slug you will need to do a 301 redirect for each page so that it goes to the new one. That way the search engines will not penalize your site. You can do a 301 redirect using an SEO plugin such as Rank Math. You may also do it by editing/adding to the .htaccess file like so:

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html http://YOUR-SITE.com/new-page.html
```